# Is it possible to extend the relationship and node limit in Neo4J?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

As I understand it there is currently a limit of around 40 billion edges in a Neo4J graph.

Is it possible to extend this? I am looking towards 100 billion to 1 trillion edges with my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the limit is on the roadmap for Neo4j 2.1.

Since Neo4j is open source, you can do it yourself - however this would require a lot of knowledge of the internals.